# Python regex multiline replacement

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I searched existing questions but they do not seem to answer this specific question.

I have the following python program

```
description = """\
before

{cs:id=841398|rep=myrepo}: after
"""
pattern = re.compile(r"(.*)\{cs:id=(.*)\|rep=(.*)\}(.*)")
```

and I need to replace the regex in the description to look like the below but I can't get the pattern and replacement syntax right

```
description="""\
before

<a href="http://crucible.app.com:9090/myrepo?cs=841398">841398</a> : after
"""
```

The crucible.app.com:9090 is a constant that I have beforehand so I basically need to substitute the pattern with my replacement.

Can someone show me what is the best python regex find and replace syntax for this?

Comment: Have you looked into [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the first and last `(.*)` in your pattern. To write back captured groups in the replacement string, use `\1` and `\2`:

```
description = re.sub(pattern, "<a href=\"http://crucible.app.com:9090/\2?cs=\1\">\1</a>", description)
```

By the way, another way to improve your pattern (performance- and robustness-wise) is to mkae the inner repetitions more explicit so that they cannot accidentally go past the `|` or `}`:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\{cs:id=([^|]*)\|rep=([^}]*)\}")
```

You can also use named groups:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\{cs:id=(?P<id>[^|]*)\|rep=(?P<rep>[^}]*)\}")
```

And then in the replacement string:

```
"<a href=\"http://crucible.app.com:9090/\g<repo>?cs=\g<id>\">\g<id></a>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) / [`RegexObject.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.sub):

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"{cs:id=(.*?)\|rep=(.*?)}")
>>> description =  pattern.sub(r'<a href="http://crucible.app.com:9090/\1?cs=\2">\1</a>', description)
>>> print(description)
before

<a href="http://crucible.app.com:9090/841398?cs=myrepo">841398</a>: after
```

`\1`, `\2` refer to matched group 1, 2.

I modified the regular expression slightly.

- No need to escape `{`, `}`.
- Removed capturing group before, after {..}.
- Used non-greedy match: `.*?`